# Stepwise edge hightlighting (tikz) doesn't work with template

Tags: tikz-pgf, highlighting, graphs

I'm just now working on a written paper for a presentation I've given and would like to reuse the graphs developed for the slides. Unfortunately the template given for the paper somehow screws with my way of highlighting edges and nodes (warning: Usage of package fancyhdr' together(scrbook) with a KOMA-Script class is not recommended.). Is there a way of quickly solving this problem (otherwise I´ll just cut the images as .pdf and enter them as graphics)?
Code works for beamer as well as article:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \newif\ifhighlight
        \tikzset{ 
            highlight/.is if=highlight,
            highlight=false,
            step number/.initial=0
        }
        \pgfkeys{
            /tikz/edgeid/.code={
                \pgfmathparse{ifthenelse(#1<=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/step number},"true","false")}
                \pgfkeys{/tikz/highlight=\pgfmathresult}
                \ifhighlight
                \tikzset{
                    ultra thick, green!80!black
                }
                \fi
            }
        }
    \newcommand{\FTidea}[1]{
            \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.6,step number=#1]
            \foreach \pos/\name/\id in {{(0,0)}/A/0,{(1,0)}/B/1,{(2,0)}/C/2,{(3,0)}/D/3,{(0,1)}/E/5,{(1,1)}/F/6,{(2,1)}/G/7,{(3,1)}/H/4}{
                \node (\name) at \pos [circle,draw] {$\name$};}
            \foreach \source/\dest/\weight/\id in {A/B/1/1,C/D/2/3,D/H/1/4,E/F/1/6,F/G/1/7,A/E/2/99,A/F/4/99,B/G/5/99,B/C/3/99,C/E/2/99,H/G/4/99}
                \draw [edgeid=\id][-] (\source) edge node{\weight} (\dest);
            \end{tikzpicture}
        }
\FTidea{0} %obviously called multiple times in the real code
\end{document}
```

As I've found the upper code part, defining ifhighlight and edgeid, online and am fairly new to LaTeX, I'm not sure how variable visibility (or parameter visibility) works, so I can't restructure it to find out, what part causes the issue (some playing around suggests that it might be the pgf stuff or the /tikz/highlight) but regular tikz drawing works and removing any edge or node coloring clears all problems as well.

Comment: If you select the code and click the code button it will format it as a block as opposed to inline marking with backticks ;)

Comment: Your code, tested in a minimal document with `article`, doesn't work at all, can you turn your snippet into a complete example that demonstrates the problem? And I don't see how the warning you mention has anything to with this, that is caused, I guess, by having `\usepackage{fancyhdr}` in a document with `scrbook`.

Comment: sry, edited the code to be complete, just the normal document environment and of cause the tikz import were missing.

Comment: Your code seems to work fine, what exactly is the problem that you see?

Comment: The code is used in a mandatory template, amongst others, useing the fancyhdr package, which is mentioned in the error in the main post. So if this is not a common problem that arises with many templates, an restructuring of the edgeid definition that works with fancyhdr would probably help me out (raw fancyhdr use does not call errors and due to copyright uncertenty I'd rather not upload the template). However I've already contacted my supervisor and still got the backup option of generating graphics in an article and using it as .pdf graphics for the main paper.

Comment: Sorry forgot to check back in, I wasn't pinged because you didn't use `@username`. If this is a mandatory template you should first of all tell the person(s) responsible to not use `fancyhdr` with KOMA-classes, so that the basic template compiles without warnings. That said, I'm going to vote to close this as unclear, I don't think it's possible to solve without having the code of the template, or a minimal example based on the template. If you can provide more info we can reopen.